# Inflection and relative extrema of a function with multiple unknowns

Tags: functions, derivatives

I can't solve the following exercise:

> Determine a, b and c so that the function $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+2$ reaches a relative maximum for $x=0$ and so that $(1,0)$ is an inflection point of the graph of f.

I do know that the function can reach a relative max. in the root of the derivative of the function and that the function has an inflection point in the root of the seconds derivative. But I don't understand how I could find a, b and c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing
$f^{′}(x) = 3ax^2+2bx+c$
$f^{′′}(x) = 6ax+2b$

Now put these equations to $0$ with respect of $x = 0$ for first equation and $x = 1$ for the second equation (based on conditions of exercise).
$$3ax^2+2bx+c = 0 \implies c = 0$$
and
$$6ax+2b = 0 \implies 6a+2b = 0$$
In order to ensure, that point $(0, 0)$ is indeed a maximum, we have to make sure that a slope before $(0, 0)$ is **negative** and after $(0, 0)$ **positive**.

That means, with respect to our exercise, choosing $x$ smaller than $0$ and bigger than $0$.

In our example, let's choose $x = -1$ and $x = 1$.
Therefore
$$3a-2b+c > 0$$
$$3a+2b+c < 0$$
The same principle applies to inflexion point, so with respect to $(1, 0)$ let's choose $x = 0$ and $x = 2$, therefore
$$2b < 0$$
$$12a+2b > 0$$

What we have is the system of linear equation
$$c = 0$$
$$6a+2b = 0$$
$$3a-2b+c > 0$$
$$3a+2b+c < 0$$
$$2b < 0$$
$$12a+2b > 0$$
That gives us
$$b = -3a \land c = 0 \land a > 0$$

Let's choose $a = 1$, therefore $b = -3$.

That is $f(x) = x^3 -3x^2+2$.

Comment: Thanks that's it!

Comment: I realized that in order to ensure that the point is global maximum, we have to constraint slopes before and after critical point (the same logic applies to inflexion point). The answer has been modified but the result is same :), sorry about that. @tomcajot